# nomencl package and vertical bar |

Tags: nomenclature

I am using the `nomencl` package; however, it seems that my nomenclature entries which contain a vertical bar | in math mode are not handled properly.  Is this a known issue, and is there a suggested workaround?

As an example, the following entry in my document

```
\nomenclature{$s(A)$}{equivalent to $|A|$}
```

makes it into the .nlo file, but not the .nls file.

Comment: I should add that, as expected, it works if I convert the | to \vert.  But is this the best solution?  I'd prefer not to have to remember to do this in nomenclature entries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **nomencl** package uses the standard MakeIndex process and `|` is a special character for the `\index` command. So there's no way unless you produce a variant of `nomencl.ist` that disables that special character:

```
%% ---- for input file ----
keyword    "\\nomenclatureentry"
%% Germans might want to change this and delete the two %%
%% quote '"'
%% ---- for output file ----
preamble   "\\begin{thenomenclature} \n"%
postamble  "\n\n\\end{thenomenclature}\n" group_skip "\n"
delim_0    ""
delim_1    ""
delim_2    ""
%% The next lines will produce some warnings when
%% running Makeindex as they try to cover two different
%% versions of the program:
lethead_prefix "\n \\nomgroup{"
lethead_suffix "}\n"
lethead_flag   1
heading_prefix "\n \\nomgroup{"
heading_suffix "}\n"
headings_flag  1
encap '?'
```

The last line is the additional one, I've put a question mark that probably you won't use in a nomenclature entry. Save the file as `mynomencl.ist` and use

```
makeindex ⟨filename ⟩.nlo -s mynomencl.ist -o ⟨filename ⟩.nls
```

to produce the `.nls` file.

It's probably better to remember `\vert` instead of `|`. By the way, the `amsmath` package provides `\lvert` and `\rvert` that should be preferred to simple bars: `\lvert A\rvert` will have correct spacing also in critical situations when `|A|` might not.

For the rare usage of `|`, you can also get around the issue with

```
\nomenclature{$s(A)$}{equivalent to $"|A"|$}
```

Comment: 1+ for \vert instead of |.