# Norm Symbol in Nomenclature not showing

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

When I have symbols like $\|\|$ in a nomenclature entry, then the entry doesn't show. Using this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature{$\|\|$}{Norm}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

I get an entry for the speed of light and the planck constant but the norm entry just falls under the bus. Is this deliberate? How can I make the norm show in the nomenclature?

Comment: Exactly what should `\|\|` mean here? Is the the norm function? Isn't that normally written as `\lVert{}\cdot{}\rVert` to mark it as a function?

Comment: `|` is one of `makeindex`'s special characters. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31562

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters, the backslash and the vertical bar:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\mbox{}

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature{$"\"|\,{\cdot}\,"\"|$}{Norm}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

On the other hand using `\lVert` and `\rVert` is simpler (and more correct)

```
\nomenclature{$\lVert\,{\cdot}\,\rVert$}{Norm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As @Nicola-Talbot pointed out, | is a special character for makeindex.  But it's better to use $\Vert$ in any case.  As an aside, I'm a big fan of the paired delimiter setup in the `mathtools` package: it ensures that you never have unmatched parentheses.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}


hello

\nomenclature{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial frame}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Planck constant}
\nomenclature{$\Vert$}{Norm}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```