# Generating vertical lines without using | in table?

Tags: tables, nomenclature

Simply put, the [nomencl](https://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl?lang=en) package sees `|` as a special character (as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31563/167081)). I am interested in inserting a table with vertical lines. If I use `|` to denote a vertical line, the entry wouldn't show in the nomenclature list.

The ideas that I can think of to overcome this is generating the table as a standalone and importing the pdf in the entry or generate the entire table using Ti*k*Z, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28103/167081).

Is there a simpler approach to adapt to?

Here is a minimal example:

```
%pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
%makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
%pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makenomenclature  
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature[1in]
    
    \nomenclature{Entry 1}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            a & a & a \\
            a & a & a \\
            a & a & a
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \nomenclature{Entry 2}{
        \begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
            b & b & b \\
            b & b & b \\
            b & b & b
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to put `!{\vrule}` instead of `|` in the preamble of the tabular.

Comment: @F.Pantigny, unfortunately, I get `Illegal character in array arg` exception.

Comment: you need `array` package for `!`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\subitem): ``c'` used is what I get.

Comment: I ran your example but get no error but empty nlo file?

Comment: Interesting, I did include the command used when executing MakeIndex in the code. It generates the nlo file with the two specified entries. However, I still get the `Illegal pream-token (\subitem):` error when running `PDFLaTeX`.

Comment: @F.Pantigny and DavidCarlisle, thank you for your time! I managed to find a solution :).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, oh, it might be because of the `[001]` argument passed. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [F. Pantigny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/163000/f-pantigny) and [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) for directing me to get to the solution.

I used the [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package and declared my own `newcolumntype` as:

`\newcolumntype{~}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}`

or (as [egreg's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) comment suggestion)

`\newcolumntype{~}{|}`

and used `\begin{tabular}{~c~c~c~}...\end{tabular}`.

[image: Output]

```
%pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
%makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
%pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{~}{!{\vrule width 1pt}}

\makenomenclature  
\makeindex

\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature[1in]
    
    \nomenclature{Entry 1}{
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            a & a & a \\
            a & a & a \\
            a & a & a
        \end{tabular}
    }
    \nomenclature{Entry 2}{
        \begin{tabular}{~c~c~c~}
            b & b & b \\
            b & b & b \\
            b & b & b
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong in `\newcolumntype{~}{|}`?

Comment: @egreg,sure! it works just as fine! It would be easier to change the width of the vertical line if needed. I did update my answer though :).